# how to install YouCompleteMe on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: python, c++, git, ubuntu, vim

I want to use YCM for C++ auto-completion.

I have walked through every step in installation guide written by Valloric, but it doesn't work.

I found a install guide that seem easier to follow with the same result, but it also doesn't work:

1. cd ~/.vim/bundle
2. git clone https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git
3. cd YouCompleteMe
4. git submodule update --init --recursive
5. ./install.sh --clang-completer
6. add to ~/.vimrc: let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py'

Am I missing something? Please help!

Comment: We are installing it by following the guide. What is wrong exactly?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? "but it doesn't work." sounds incomplete. Is any error in messages?

Comment: 1) You should tell us what is going wrong with your posted method. 2) It looks like you're putting everything in the bundle directory but you're not actually using Vundle or anything? Why? 3) What went wrong with Valloric's [Ubuntu Linux x64 super-quick installation](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#ubuntu-linux-x64-super-quick-installation) that made you abandon that method?

Comment: thank for quick responses. I try to edit some .cpp file, and there is no completion happend. During installation, no error occurs.

Comment: Can you give us the results of running `:YcmDebugInfo` in vim?

Comment: Do you mean type ":YcmDebugInfo" in vim. It says "E492: Not an editor command: YcmDebugInfo"

Comment: thank  **anonymous coward**, I found my mistake. I have deleted "Plugin  Valloric/YouCompleteMe" in ~/.vimrc after installed YCM through Vundle,